# Ruby 2.6.6 OpenSSL 1.1.1g - certificate verify failed (unable to get local issuer certificate)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl, openssl, activemerchant

Run into an issue today after [checkout.com](https://www.checkout.com/) updated their SSL certificates to SSLv3. Here's the output from logs:

```
Gateway Error
30 May 2020 16:28:29.123147 <190>1 2020-05-30T15:28:28.906445+00:00 app web.1 - - --- !ruby/exception:ActiveMerchant::ConnectionError
30 May 2020 16:28:29.123167 <190>1 2020-05-30T15:28:28.906447+00:00 app web.1 - - message: The SSL connection to the remote server could not be established
30 May 2020 16:28:29.123154 <190>1 2020-05-30T15:28:28.906447+00:00 app web.1 - - triggering_exception: !ruby/exception:OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError
30 May 2020 16:28:29.123175 <190>1 2020-05-30T15:28:28.906448+00:00 app web.1 - - message: 'SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B:
30 May 2020 16:28:29.123165 <190>1 2020-05-30T15:28:28.906449+00:00 app web.1 - - certificate verify failed (unable to get local issuer certificate)'
30 May 2020 16:28:29.12394 <190>1 2020-05-30T15:28:28.906449+00:00 app web.1 - -
```

Since they've update their SSL certs we're experiencing this issue.

Our app is built on an older version of Solidus, v1.3.2 which uses ActiveMerchant v1.48.0. Updating ActiveMerchant doesn't appear to be possible due to the Gemspec, and we've heavily modified Solidus so we can't easily update that either.

Anyone have any ideas how to get this resolved?

Answer (score 0):

We faced the same problem while using the gem with checkout.com, you could try this fix currently in PR on active_merchant
https://github.com/activemerchant/active_merchant/pull/3704